# Adding a Button below a WebView

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

I have to show a fragment of text **formatted in HTML** (a terms and conditions text). Below this text, there should be a `Button` to accept them.

Of course, the user should scroll down to the bottom before accepting the terms, so the button should be just under the terms & conditions text.

I have used a `WebView` to render the HTML, **but it has a big problem**: When I put it inside a `StackPanel`, it **collapses its height to zero**. So, nothing is shown. This is the XAML to reproduce the problem.

```
<StackPanel>
    <WebView />
    <Button>Accept</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

This doesn't happen when the container is a **Grid**, because it expands to fill the whole space. However, with a Grid I cannot make the `Button` appear under the text.

What can I do to make this work?

Comment: Have you tried with *RelativePanel*?

Comment: Should WebView get the whole available space but the button below? Have you tried with suitable Rows?

Comment: @Romasz Yes, it should take all the space available and the button must appear below. They may be scrolling, because the text is long. Do you think a RelativePanel will do the trick?

Comment: RelativePanel seems to behave the same as StackPanel (as I've tested). Can they scroll inside WebView or the WebView should be scrolled with outer scrollviewer? I think I've managed to do what you want with Grid.

Answer (score 1):

You should add Rows to the Grid:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!-- This row will be stretched -->
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>

        <!-- The size of this row is determined by the size properties of the content object. -->
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <WebView Grid.Row="0"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="1">Accept</Button>
</Grid>
```

Take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/layout-panels) for more info about layout panels in UWP.